# CassandraBatchOperations add string queries

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data, cql

I have written the below code:

```
@Service
public class CassandraBatchOperationService {
@Autowired CassandraTemplate cassandraTemplate;
public void batchOps(List<Object>entities){
        CassandraBatchOperations batchCql = cassandraTemplate.batchOps().insert(entities);
        batchCql.execute(); 
}}
```

I know how it is working and it is fine. But I want to know is there any possibility to add query strings(`"INSERT INTO table1(value1,value2) VALUES ('test','test');"`) to *CassandraBatchOperations* objects? I expect something similar below:

```
@Service
public class CassandraBatchOperationService {
@Autowired CassandraTemplate cassandraTemplate;
public void batchOps(List<Object>entities,List<String> queries){
        CassandraBatchOperations batchCql = cassandraTemplate.batchOps().insert(entities).insert(queries);
        batchCql.execute(); 
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Batch Raw Query:**

```
UUID uuid = UUIDs.timeBased();
String insertPreparedCql = 
  "insert into book (isbn, title, publisher, tags) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
List<Object> singleBookArgsList = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<?>> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
singleBookArgsList.add(uuid);
singleBookArgsList.add("Head First Java");
singleBookArgsList.add("OReilly Media");
singleBookArgsList.add(ImmutableSet.of("Software"));
bookList.add(singleBookArgsList);
cassandraTemplate.ingest(insertPreparedCql, bookList);
```

**If possible with batch statement (ignoring the orm mapping ):**

```
//session is your cassandra session
BatchStatement insertBatch = new BatchStatement();

PreparedStatement insertQuery =  session.prepare("INSERT ......"); 
PreparedStatement insertQuery2 =  session.prepare("INSERT ......"); 
    .
    .
insertBatch.add(insertQuery);
insertBatch.add(insertQuery2);
...
session.execute(insertBatch);
```